# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.isRunning()" because "this.process" is null

Tags: appium-android, appium-java

When I am executing the script then it is giving me an error as : Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.isRunning()" because "this.process" is null

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass ConfigureAppium
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.isRunning()" because "this.process" is null
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.destroyProcess(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:220)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.destroyProcess(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:253)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.start(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:176)
at appiumtest.appium.BaseTest.ConfigureAppium(BaseTest.java:33)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 3):

The following solution solved my problem

Solved it by going to `$HOME/.m2/repository/io/appium/java-client/8.3.0` and adjusting the file: java-client-8.3.0.pom . Changing all selenium related dependencies’ version tag from: `<version>[4.7.0, 5.0)</version>` to `<version>[4.7.0, 4.8.2)</version>` to eliminate incompatible 4.8.2 selenium version.

Original post: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1872#issuecomment-1484017595

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer by Eduardo, I would rather update the project's pom.xml and add "exclusions" rather than editing the repository files

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependency>
```